# Beginner: Hyperbola asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner to asymptotes with hyperbola.

Jane Sterling, the author of Algebra II for dummies, writes the following:

[image]

Whereas Khan ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0Fd2Tg2v7M)) solves for y as x approaches infinity (x's positive limit) to find the asymptotes. My question is **why** does Sterling's method work? Specifically, how can you set 1 to 0 and then set the two equations equal to each other? I don't understand that algebraic trick.

Comment: Because $\frac{(y+4)^2}{16}+1  \approx \frac{(y+4)^2}{16}$ when $y$ becomes very large.

Comment: That helps. Thanks! I forgot that, given a + b = 0, a = b because zero is the identity element for addition.